# C# LINQ To SQL Classes

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linq-to-sql

I made a LINQ to SQL Classes file *DataClasses.dbml*. When i drag a table in it is ok and everything works but I was wondering can i put to columns together using the *Source* property where the column name is passed? 
example Name+Surname

[image: Memeber property properties]

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do it, becouse in property window you can just write name of one column that will be bind your property. It's just to this ORM Framework works.

However you can do it other way.

First way is to extend your table class becouse all classes in `.dbml` autogenerated file are `partial`. So you can write property with `return Name + Surname;`

Second way is to write stored procedure in your database that returns `NameAndSurname` field and drop it to your `.dbml` file like you already have done with table.